# Express.js and intercepting .js requests and serving .gz instead

Tags: express, gzip

So, I am using webpack to compress/gzip my js files. Then I want to use my Express server to serve those up when a .js request comes in. I am having a devil of a time getting this to work in production. I am able to in dev. I feel it has to do with how I am setting my static files. Assitance?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// THIS is not working
app.get("*.js", function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    next();
});
```

I tried positioning above, middle etc.. of the above code. Not working. I know my webpack is building it as I see the output in the build folder. I just can't seem to get my express server to serve up the .gz version.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in production you are running version 2.x and in dev you are using 3.x. 
As per http://51elliot.blogspot.com/2012/08/serve-gzipped-files-with-expressjs.html you can see that...

For 2.x

```
// basic URL rewrite to serve gzipped versions of *.min.js files
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  next();
});
```

and for 3.x:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  next();
});
```

NOTE: I have not tried this, just a hunch.

Comment: Romain - thanks. Is there anything, you notice  - wrong with my ordering? Even when I try to console for the request nothing ever comes thru with the "*.js" /get route.

Comment: @jamesemanon - Which version are you using. Notice one does a set and the other header on the response.

Comment: Could also be a firewall issue.